# embeded line seperation R Markdown tabset

Tags: r, r-markdown

after searching for a while I can't figure out how to get out of a tabset section in my Rmarkdown.
Here an example :

```
#Section 1 
## subsection 1.1 {.tabset}

## subection 1.2 {.tabset}
### var1
### var2
---
#Section 2
```

My probleme is that I would like the line --- (or

---

since I'm rendering an html file) to be between section 1 and section 2 and don't want it to be considered as a part of the ###var2 section and be embedded in the tabset.
With this code, I only see my line when I have clicked in the var2 section of the tabset

my first idea is to do something like that

```
#Section 1 
<div>
## subsection 1.1 {.tabset}

## subection 1.2 {.tabset}
### var1
### var2
</div>
---
#Section 2
```

but I feel like this is not the most elegent way to solve that since I already activeted section-divs: true in my yaml options which mean I am recreating div section above others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use some CSS to automatically insert a line before each section.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Stéphane Laurent"
date: "2023-06-16"
output:
  html_document:
    css: "style.css"
---

# Section 1 

## subsection 1.1 {.tabset}

## subsection 1.2 {.tabset}

### var1

### var2

# Section 2
```

```css
/* file style.css */
h1:not(.title)::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can use a CSS class if you don't want a line for every section.

Answer (score 1):

You could end the tabset with a new section of an upper level. With `{-}` you can create an empty header like this:

```
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

# Section 1 
## subsection 1.1 {.tabset}

## subection 1.2 {.tabset}
### var1
### var2

## {-}

---

# Section 2
```

Output:

[image]